# Try to add content type to list. Error: System.ArgumentException: No two choices should have the same ID

Tags: list, content-type

I am using SP 2010. I have a list. I have 5 content types on this list.

I try to add another one. When I click on the link "Add from existing site content types" I got an error from SharePoint with a correlation id.

When I search for the error in ULS by correlation id I got these errors below:

```
01/30/2015 15:39:32.39  w3wp.exe (NLSP001:0x24AC)                   0x2F48  Document Management Server      Document Management             52od    Medium  MetadataNavigationContext Page_InitComplete: No XsltListViewWebPart was found on this page[/_layouts/AddContentTypeToList.aspx?List=%7B99B68B83%2D19BE%2D40AD%2D94FF%2DEBBE43AB4357%7D].  Hiding key filters and downgrading tree functionality to legacy ListViewWebPart(v3) level for this list.  15228a9c-2297-4192-8cd2-1f53fa8c8c9d
01/30/2015 15:39:32.90  w3wp.exe (NLSP001:0x24AC)                   0x2F48  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.ArgumentException: No two choices should have the same ID    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ChoiceComparerWithDefaultGroup.Compare(PickerItem c1, PickerItem c2)     at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.QuickSort(T[] keys, Int32 left, Int32 right, IComparer`1 comparer)     at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.QuickSort(T[] keys, Int32 left, Int32 right, IComparer`1 comparer)     at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.Sort(T[] keys, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer) 15228a9c-2297-4192-8cd2-1f53fa8c8c9d
```

When I create a new list in the same website and try to add a content type I got the same error. When I try it on another website it works fine. What is my issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you experience this behaviour you probably have a problem related to duplicated site columns somewhere.

This gentleman helps identifying the ID on

> No two choices should have the same ID

https://sharepointdiva.wordpress.com/2012/08/16/no-two-choices-should-have-the-same-id/

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities are there :

1) Check the content types GUID is not duplicate. other wise it conflicts.

2) Check all the site columns have a unique GUID in all the content type and check there must be not repetition of site column in content type ELEMENT.XML